# How to pass a value to container component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

In my todo app, i have two selectors:

```js
export const selectFilter = (state: RootState) => state.visibilityFilter
export const selectVisibleTodos = createSelector(
  [selectTodos, selectFilter],
  (todos: Todo[], filter : VisibilityFilters) => {
    switch (filter) {
      case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ALL:
        return todos
      case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_COMPLETED:
        return todos.filter((todo) => todo.completed)
      case VisibilityFilters.SHOW_ACTIVE:
        return todos.filter((todo) => !todo.completed)
      default:
        return todos
    }
  }
)

export const selectByDescription = createSelector(
  [selectVisibleTodos, (state: RootState, searchText: string) => searchText],
  (todos: Todo[], value: string) => {
    return todos.filter((todo) => todo.title.includes(value))
  }
)
```

The second selector take a value (`searchText`) wroted by user. I had two more components:

My `VisibleTodos.tsx` (a connector to `TodoList.tsx`):

```js
import { selectVisibleTodos } from '../features/filter/filterSlice'

const mapState = (state: RootState) => ({
  visibleTodos: selectVisibleTodos(state)
})

const mapDispatch = {
  onClickOnItem: todoDeleted
}

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

export interface TodoListProps extends PropsFromRedux {}
export default connector(TodoList)
```

And the `TodoList.jsx` itself

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import TodoItem from './TodoItem'
import { TodoListProps } from '../../containers/VisibleTodos'
import { Todo } from './todoSlice'
import { RootState } from '../../app/store'

const TodoList = ({ visibleTodos, onClickOnItem }: TodoListProps) => {
  const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState<string>('')
  const onChange = (e : React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => setSearchText(e.currentTarget.value)

  return (
    <>
      {/* How i pass searchText to the VisibleTodos.tsx from here?*/}
      <input placeholder="Faça sua pesquisa" type="search" onChange={onChange} value={searchText} />
      <ul style={{listStyle: 'none'}}>
        {
          visibleTodos.map(
            (todo : Todo) =>
              <TodoItem todo={todo} key={todo.id} onClickProp={onClickOnItem}/>
          )
        }
      </ul>
    </>
  )

}

export default TodoList
```

I want `visibleTodos` to be only responsible for rendering the list, without knowing the value of `searchText`, but how i pass `searchText` value to `VisibleTodos.tsx` connector component?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following way. Add searchText in mapstate and destructure in TodoList.tsx component.

```
import { selectVisibleTodos } from '../features/filter/filterSlice'

const mapState = (state: RootState,Ownprops:TodoListProps) => ({
  visibleTodos: selectVisibleTodos(state)
  searchText: selectSearchText(Ownprops.any props selector required.)
})

const mapDispatch = {
  onClickOnItem: todoDeleted
}

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)
type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<typeof connector>

export interface TodoListProps extends PropsFromRedux {}
export default connector(TodoList)
```

Comment: I want visibleTodos to be only responsible for rendering the list, without knowing the value of searchText. I can do something like that?

```
import { selectByDescription } from '../features/filter/filterSlice'

const mapState = (state: RootState, ownProps) => ({
  visibleTodos: selectByDescription(state, ownProps.searchText)
})
```

Comment: How would my component TodoList look? I'm having trouble seeing this

Comment: as you are already passing visibletodos to the to-do list component, you don't have to do anything more. basically, you are filtering data before connect. it should work

Comment: will that help?

Comment: Not so much. I'm confused yet, can u send my an example in sandbox?